# Why am I getting empty arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, variables, methods, instance

My intention is to fill up different arrays with numbers and strings in different methods in an object.

But it seems that I have a problem.

Here is the code:

```
package arrays;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Notendurchschnitt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        NotenManager noten = new NotenManager();
        noten.eingabe();
        noten.ausgabeDesArrays();
    }

}

class NotenManager {

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
double[] notenArray;
String[] vornamen;
String[] nachnamen;


void eingabe() {

    System.out.print("Wieviele Personen haben\nan der Kausur teilgenommen? ");
    double[] notenArray=new double[scanner.nextInt()];
    String[] vornamen=new String[notenArray.length];
    String[] nachnamen=new String[notenArray.length];
    scanner.nextLine();

    for (int i=0;i<notenArray.length;i++) {
        System.out.printf("%d.Teilnehmer\nVorname: ",i+1);
        vornamen[i]=scanner.nextLine();
         System.out.print("Nachname: ");
         nachnamen[i]=scanner.nextLine();
         System.out.print("Note: ");
         scanner.nextLine();

    }



}

 void ausgabeDesArrays() {


     double ergebnis=0;


        System.out.println("Zahl der Eintraege:."+notenArray[0]+".");



    }
}
```

The Compiler gives me an `NullPointerException-Error` because the array `notenanArray` in the method `ausgabe()` is not filled with the values which were created for the array `notenArray` in the method `eingabe()`.

Why is the array filled with nulls, even though it is an instance variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring `notenArray`, `vornamen`, `nachnamen` twice (One as a class attribute, and one locally in the method `eingabe`). By doing this, you are entering values to the **local arrays**, so when you try to print the first element in the method `ausgabeDesArrays()`, it throws an Exception since the "global" `notenArray` is not initialized.

To correct the problem change these lines:

```
double[] notenArray = new double[scanner.nextInt()];
String[] vornamen = new String[notenArray.length];
String[] nachnamen = new String[notenArray.length];
```

with

```
notenArray = new double[scanner.nextInt()];
vornamen = new String[notenArray.length];
nachnamen = new String[notenArray.length];
```

Comment: To clarify: the second declaration (in the scope of `eingabe` ) "overrides" the global declaration - you end up with a local variable whose scope is limited to the function in which it was created.

Answer (score 1):

You are shadowing your `NotenManager`  class attributes with `eingabe` method  local variables declarations:

```
double[] notenArray = new double[scanner.nextInt()];
String[] vornamen = new String[notenArray.length];
String[] nachnamen = new String[notenArray.length];
```

You don't need to redecalre them just intialized:

```
notenArray = new double[scanner.nextInt()];
vornamen = new String[notenArray.length];
nachnamen = new String[notenArray.length];
```

method local variables have no effect on your class attributes and hence your class attributes are always null.